# Search user using part of the name

Tags: php, sql, search

I have this PHP code:

```
function getusers($user) {
    $result = query("SELECT IdUser, username FROM login WHERE username='%s'",$user);

    if (count($result['result'])>0) {
        //authorized

        print json_encode($result);
    } else {
        errorJson('Actualization failed');
    }
}
```

But this only returns the user that matches the name exactly.
I'd like to return all users containing that name string, for example:

dani -> daniel, dani_56, dani563, elnenedani, ...

It is usually done by putting in PHP: `%dani%` but as I have put the %s to grab the variable $user, I do not know how to put it.

Any idea?

Comment: I hope that `query()` function is doing some some proper placeholder prep, or at least escaping parameters, because otherwise you're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Could you post the function `query()` so we can see what it is doing?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a great Question. If you have searched well in Stackoverflow you would have go it the answer.. As you asked the Question the answer is.. Instead of Equal use LIKE:

```
function getusers($user) {
$result = query("SELECT IdUser, username FROM login WHERE username LIKE %'%s'%",$user);

if (count($result['result'])>0) {
    //authorized

    print json_encode($result);
} else {
    errorJson('Actualization failed');
}
}
```

It seems the PHP code and DB is working well. Checkout the below links for the error:

[iOS 5 JSON Parsing Results in Cocoa Error 3840](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174130/ios-5-json-parsing-results-in-cocoa-error-3840)

[Cocoa error 3840 using JSON (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171111/cocoa-error-3840-using-json-ios)

[The Operation couldn't be completed. (Cocoa error: 3840.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534289/the-operation-couldnt-be-completed-cocoa-error-3840)

[Cocoa Error 3840 - NSJSONSerialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282771/cocoa-error-3840-nsjsonserialization)

Comment: thanks friend, but this fails: $result = query("SELECT IdUser, username FROM login WHERE username LIKE %'%s'%",$user);

Comment: I´m receive this: error -> The operation couldn´t be comleted. (Cocoa error 3840.)

Comment: it seems the error is not with the DB link or search.. check out the below links..

Answer (score 0):

You should use the LIKE syntax. Make sure to include `%` to indicate wildcards:

```
query('SELECT IdUser, username FROM login 
       WHERE username LIKE "%' . $user . '%"')
```

Comment: thanks friend, but this fails: $result = query("SELECT IdUser, username FROM login WHERE username LIKE %'%s'%",$user);

Comment: This is a parsing issue. See above.

Comment: I understand why you changed the syntax, I do not remember but it's true that you can also write well, but still does not work for me and do not understand.
Should work with mySql and working, this is for an iOS app that works with JSON maybe that has something to do

Answer (score 0):

My query() function is

```
function query() {
global $link;
$debug = false;

//get the sql query
$args = func_get_args();
$sql = array_shift($args);

//secure the input
for ($i=0;$i<count($args);$i++) {
    $args[$i] = urldecode($args[$i]);
    $args[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $args[$i]);
}

//build the final query
$sql = vsprintf($sql, $args);

if ($debug) print $sql;

//execute and fetch the results
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if (mysqli_errno($link)==0 && $result) {

    $rows = array();

    if ($result!==true)
    while ($d = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($rows,$d);
    }

    //return json
    return array('result'=>$rows);

} else {

    //error
    return array('error'=>'Database error');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I do not get fixed. This code is for an ios app that uses AFNetworking, might please that helps you know what happens because I do not get it